# Why ChildNode property not working if try to get an element using getElementByClassName

Tags: javascript, dom

I am trying to access the child nodes of a parent element. If i use the getElementById then i can use the property "childNodes" but if i use byClassName the this property "childNodes" is not working.

```
<div id="strop" class="strop">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="child" id="first">Child1</div>
        <div class="child">Child2
          <ul class="ul">
            <li class="ulchild">L1</li>
            <li class="ulchild">L2</li>
            <li class="ulchild">L3</li>
            <li class="ulchild">L4</li>
            <li class="ulchild">L5</li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="child">child3</div>
        <div class="child">child4</div>
      </div>
```

```
////////////getting element by id//////////

let a = document.getElementById('strop');
console.log(a.childNodes)
//return html collection

// / getting element by classname ////////////

let b = document.getElementsByClassName('strop');
console.log(b.childNodes)
//returns undefined
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`getElementsByClassName` will return an array, not a single element, and thus you'd want to do something like `getElementsByClassName('strop')[0].childNodes`